# PHP json_encode html element contains unwanted white space

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a problem here.

`index.php`

```
ob_start();
include '../view/user.php';
$include = ob_get_clean();

echo json_encode(array(
"success" => true,
"status" => "ok",
"data" => $include));
```

`user.php`

```
<div>
<h2 class='workspace-name'>
<?php echo $name; ?>
</h2>
</div>
```

The problem is if I indent the HTML element in `user.php` properly (for readability), there will be a lot of `\r\n\t\t\t`, provided I use `jquery.get` to get JSON dataType.

How do I get rid of the `/r/t/n`? Although it doesn't display on screen I don't feel right about it. Is there any better solution?
Any question please drop in the comment I will edit this. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace) to replace those characters.

```
"data" => str_replace(array("\n","\r","\t"),'',$include)));
```

**EDIT:** Or use the following when dealing with HTML like `<a\thref='#'>Click\n\nHere</a>` (thanks to @Salman A for pointing this out)

```
"data" => str_replace(array("\n","\r","\t"),' ',$include)));
```

Comment: Simple and avoids the need to invoke the regex engine. This should work just fine.

Comment: This is a bad example actually. `<a\thref="foo">click\r\nhere</a>` is valid HTML which  should display a link with text `click here` but it is turned to `<ahref="foo">clickhere</a>`. The tag is broken and the text becomes one word.

Comment: Eugh, well a simple solution is to make sure the HTML is not in this format? Seeing as it's generated via ../view/user.php means he can make sure the HTML isn't in that format. Whilst you make a valid point, the point of white space is that it doesn't affect the output of the code.

Comment: Well, in your first example you removed too many white-space. In your second example you will end up with extra spaces :) I hope this answers both of your comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is so ugly, but it is how I do it:

```
$html = str_replace("\t",'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',$html);
$html = str_replace("\r\n",'<br />',$html);
```

I'll be following this for a better answer. There must be a regex way.

Answer (score -1):

```
$include = preg_replace("@[\\r|\\n|\\t]+@", "", ob_get_clean());
```